# C# with CLI project EXE installed through WIX installer doesnt work

Tags: c#, c++, dll, wix, command-line-interface

I have a C# project that calls C++ CLI through a DLL. It returns a string to C# which is displayed in a text box on a button event. I have added this dll(**named MyDll.dll**) by adding it as a reference in my C# project properties. I am trying to create a installer using wix toolset. Here's the source code.

**C# Code**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

using MyDll;

namespace MyProject
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Class1 obj = new Class1(); 

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string str = "";
            string str_new = obj.MyFunc(str);

            textBox1.Text = str_new;
        }
    }
}
```

**C++ CLI Code**

```
#include "stdafx.h"

#include "MyDll.h"

namespace MyDll
{
    Class1::Class1(){}
    Class1::~Class1(){}
    Class1::!Class1(){}

    String^ Class1::MyFunc([Out] String^ str)
    {
        str = "My C++/Cli DLL";
        return outVal = str;
    }
}
```

**C++ CLI Header**

```
// MyDll.h

#pragma once

using namespace System;
using namespace System::Runtime::InteropServices;

namespace MyDll {

    public ref class Class1
    {
        // TODO: Add your methods for this class here.
    public:
        Class1::Class1();
        Class1::~Class1();
        Class1::!Class1();

        String^ MyFunc([Out] String^ str);

        String^ outVal;
    };
}
```

**My WXS File**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Wix xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/2006/wi">
    <Product Id="*" Name="installer_test" Language="1033" Version="1.0.0.0" Manufacturer="Company" UpgradeCode="a928c48a-8e5b-4038-b871-939ff8a9349f">
        <Package InstallerVersion="200" Compressed="yes" InstallScope="perMachine" />

        <MajorUpgrade DowngradeErrorMessage="A newer version of [ProductName] is already installed." />
        <MediaTemplate />

        <Feature Id="ProductFeature" Title="installer_test" Level="1">
            <ComponentGroupRef Id="ProductComponents" />
        </Feature>
    </Product>

  <Fragment>
    <Property Id="ROOTDRIVE">
      <![CDATA[E:\]]>
    </Property>
    <Directory Id="TARGETDIR" Name="SourceDir">
      <Directory Id="ProgramFiles" Name="ProgramFiles">
        <Directory Id="TopFolder" Name="EXE3">
          <Directory Id="INSTALLFOLDER" Name="Main folder">
            <Component Id="cmpMain" Guid="{0509AAED-64A8-43F6-8935-70FB12305189}" KeyPath="yes" Feature="ProductFeature">
              <File Source="$(var.MyProject.TargetPath)" />
              <File Source="$(var.MyProject.TargetPath)" Name="MyDll.dll" ShortName="AF" />
            </Component>


          </Directory>
        </Directory>
      </Directory>
    </Directory>
    <Property Id="WIXUI_INSTALLDIR" Value="INSTALLFOLDER"></Property>
    <UIRef Id="WixUI_InstallDir"/>
  </Fragment>
    <Fragment>
        <ComponentGroup Id="ProductComponents" Directory="INSTALLFOLDER">
            <!-- TODO: Remove the comments around this Component element and the ComponentRef below in order to add resources to this installer. -->
            <!-- <Component Id="ProductComponent"> -->
      <!--    <File Source="$(var.MyProject.TargetPath)"/>-->
         <!-- TODO: Insert files, registry keys, and other resources here. -->
      <!--   </Component> -->



    </ComponentGroup>
    </Fragment>
</Wix>
```

My installer works fine. It installs an exe and a dll(**MyDll.dll**) with it at the specified path. But when I run the exe, it doesn't do anything. If I replace the installed exe with the exe that gets created in the bin folder of my C# project then it works fine. How can I resolve this problem?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The error lies in these 2 lines:

```
          <File Source="$(var.MyProject.TargetPath)" />
          <File Source="$(var.MyProject.TargetPath)" Name="MyDll.dll" ShortName="AF" />
```

if `$(var.MyProject.TargetPath)` is your exe file, then you are installing it twice, the second time just naming it MyDll.dll. No original dll gets installed.

Make it like

```
<File Source="$(var.MyProject.TargetPathExe)" />
<File Source="$(var.MyProject.TargetPathDll)" />
```

where the variables contain paths to your source exe and dll file.